# How can I make this 3D logo effect in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo, 3d

I have a 2D logo but not sure where to start to create the [3d Logo pictured here](https://fiverr-res.cloudinary.com/images/q_auto,f_auto/gigs/156693191/original/75e182e8326b38f1391304c1144fcd982de15a60/3d-gaming-logo-design-5240.jpg).

Is PS even where I should begin?

I mainly want to copy the 3D effect and the neon outline/stroke but not necessarily the texture on the logo.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Very few of us want to draw this for you. But you can get some hints. At first the glows. In simpler programs than Photoshop or Illustrator one can have a dark background and a brighter color spot on it in a new layer:

[image]

If the color spot gets heavy Gaussian Blur it can well be seen as a glow caused by even brighter top layer shape (=white rectangle here):

[image]

The trick is needed so often that Photoshop and Illustrator have got effect Outer Glow. In Photoshop it's one of layer styles:

[image]

It's very useful. There's no need for an extra layer, the effect is re-adjustable (color, size, decay curve, opacity noise content etc...), it moves and its form adapts if you edit the shape.

Some of your shapes seem also to have inner glows. In the next image the rightmost rectangle in the top layer has white Inner Glow:

[image]

Sometimes you may want only the effect, not the actual shape that originally got it. Reducing Layer Fill% makes the actual shape transparent, but leaves the layer style effect:

[image]

The original shape is invisible with Fill=0%. Reducing layer opacity affects equally both the original layer content and layer styles. I said styles - one can insert several layer styles simultaneously.

About 3D

Photoshop doesn't have especially rich 3D geometry creation tools. It's limited to simple extrusions, height maps, some preset 3D shapes and showing flat images as levitating cards with perspective. Effect 3D > Repousse generates extrusions.

Illustrator has also 3D revolve which generates round revolution shapes.

I skip all 3D effects because they are not needed if the case is this simple. Learn them from manuals and tutorials. And do plenty of practicing. In Photoshop you can make rectangular, polygonal lasso- and other selections and fill areas in different layers with different colors. This one has 3 items:

[image]

If we move the parts a little we can see that only the rectangle in Layer 1 is perfect. Other selections were far from perfect. Most overlaps are invisible. Only the visible overhangs are deleted by making a selection and pressing DEL in different layers:

[image]

But layer styles may need that there's no overlapping parts. You may not want a glow with wrong size, for example. To remove overlaps You can exactly select a shape in a layer by clicking its icon in the Layers panel and holding the Ctrl key. With that selection you delete in other layers whats behind. Start from the top. Doing it and moving the parts apart again shows that perfect pieces can be got:

[image]

Horizontal and vertical lines: Hold shift key if you want to limit the movement of the drawing or selection tool.

About using Illustrator: Logos are generally made as vectors because scaling to different sizes doesn't cause problems. In Photoshop you must have in the beginning the largest pixel dimensions that you expect ever will be needed for sharp image.

In Illustrator you will have difficulties to generate as rich images as your background and fill shapes are. In Photoshop you can for example use Liquify and other distortion effects. Doing the same in Illustrator soon makes the image so complex that it slows down the program.